# Regex matching with a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a string pattern like below.

abcd;abcd;sdfdf;sdfdf;sdsdf;

1. ';' should appear at most 5 times.(or less)
2. if 5th ';' is at the end no characters should be followed after that
3. between two ';' s any character could be there.
4. Number of characters between two ";" are 5.

I used following regex expression. But it doesn't give desired results.

```
(((.{0,5});){0,4}([^;]{0,5})){1}
```

Once the entire string is not matching it should be unmatched.

I'm not aware how to make the last character ';' or empty. So that is not included in the logic above I've provided.

To elaborate more
Following patterns are allowed.

```
sdfsg;;;;;
sfdsf;sdfsd;sfsdf;;
;;;;
```

unmatching examples

```
sdfsdf;sdfsd;sdf;sdfd;sdf;sdf;sdf
```

I'd really appreciate if somebody could help. If you provide an solution please kindly give an explanation so it'll help to learn.

Comment: Do you really need regex? Why don't you just split the string on `;` and check the result?

Comment: This is for validation purposes. So you get the idea right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches all those rules

```
^([^;]{0,5};){0,4}[^;]{0,5};?$
```

the `([^;]{0,5};)` matches any set of letters or nothing before a semicolon and the semicolon itself, the `{0,4}` makes sure there aren't more than 4 semicolons before the last character, the `[^;]{0,5}` matches any character after the last semicolon, the `;?` matches 1 or no semicolon as the very last character, and the `$` makes sure there aren't any characters after the last semicolon.

Comment: problem is for the last segment semicolon can be there or not.

Comment: Your second rule prevents that from happening

Comment: Nope I specified 5th. because only 5 semicolons are alowed. What if user adds 4 semicolons

Comment: @Natecat: What he meant is for `5th` semicolon. Not prior to that.

Comment: it can be something like this. sdfsd;sf;sdf; or sdfs;sdfs;sfsd
both are allowed

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi The new regex should fix that problem

Comment: ^([^;]{0,5};){0,4}[^;]*;?$

Comment: This matches for this also sfsd;sdf;sdf;sdff;sfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdf;

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi There fixed that

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex

```
^(?:[^;]{0,5};){1,4}(?:[^;]{0,5};?)?$
```

Visual explain [https://regexper.com/#^%28%3F%3A[^%3B]{0%2C5}%3B%29{1%2C4}%28%3F%3A[^%3B]{0%2C5}%3B%3F%29%3F%24](https://regexper.com/#%5E%28%3F%3A[%5E%3B]%7B0%2C5%7D%3B%29%7B1%2C4%7D%28%3F%3A[%5E%3B]%7B0%2C5%7D%3B%3F%29%3F%24)

- With `^` we match start of Line
- `(?:)` is a non capturing group (like `()` but don't store result to a groups)
- With `[^;]` we match all char except ;
- `{0,5}` catch 0 to 5 non ; char
- `;` at the end we have a final ;
- `{1,4}` we match the previous pattern pattern from 1 to 4 time inclusive
- `;?` the last ; is optinal but we can't have another char after
- `$` the end of line

Comment: I want to limit charachters between two ";" for 5 also

Comment: Try the second regex

Comment: Thanks this works. Would you please provide an explanation? So I can accept this

Comment: Is the explain is OK for you (sry if it's isn't clear i'm tired)

Comment: Not matching to this sfsd;sdf;sdf;sdfd;ddf Sorry I found the issue just now

Comment: i have modify the regex to match with your new sentence

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
(?:[^;]*;?){1,5}
```

It will capture anything between `;` and upto 5 times.

See demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bF9uN9/1)